# itunes alternative that will sync with an android

Tags: rhythmbox, music

Apparently there's a bit of a workaround with rhythmbox to get it to sync with an android. Is there a really good piece of software that syncs easily with any type of phone? Or at least allows you easily send files to your device with no hassle?

Or can rhythmbox sync quite easily with an Android and that was an old article? In this case, how can I setup rhythmbox to sync with android?

Comment: What do you mean by "sync"? Just media files alone, or play data such as playcount and last played date? If the latter, I don't think it exists. If just the former, I know that Nightingale can sync pretty well (although I have other problems with it). Part of the difficulty is syncing ext4 (your computer, presumably) with fat32 (android SD card). Fat32 fails with many filenames.

Comment: I tell you a method.You can use iTools.Because iTools can convert music to any apple device [iTunes alternative](http://www.kiwigeeker.com/music-transfer-wiki/itunes-alternative-manage-music.html), Frist,use iTools transfer playlist from Apple devices on your PC.
then,copy playlist to the internal memory in the Android mobile phone.
You can [transfer iTunes playlist to the Android](http://www.kiwigeeker.com/music-transfer-wiki/transfer-itunes-playlists-to-android.html).
It is so simple！

Answer (score 0):

**music sync for android on linux**

**Banshee, Clementine**

First make sure device is connected via usb cable :)

**For Banshee:**

start banshee

import music via: right click (and hold) Libraries -> Music and choose Import Media -

Folders -> Choose Folders (please note that it won't scan the music if it's too deep in subdirs, for me it worked only up to level artist/album/songs)

wait for scan to complete

drag and drop anything from Libraries -> Music to Devices -> [Device name] -> Music

moreover you can manage (remove,...) your library on the device by activating Devices

[Device name] -> Music and doing the needed

**For Clementine:**

start clementine

import music via menu: Tools -> Preferences -> Music Library

choose Add new folder

as you connected the device, you should see it in Devices -> [Device name]

in Library right click on album and choose Copy to device
choose Destination (your [Device name]) and click OK
moreover you can manage (remove,...) your library on the device by activating Devices

[Device name] and doing the needed

Then sync happens, whenever device is disconnected you're done